# "Performance Options" windows is opened after login on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, pagefile

After logging in my Windows account, the *Performance Options* windows is opened on the *Advanced* tab. What's the problem? How to stop it?

Comment: Related question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/951617/performance-options-window-after-rdp-login-on-windows-server-2008-r2), but not quite the same, as it seems he had non zero paging file size in total.

Answer (score 4):

Windows is trying to tell you that it failed to create any paging file. In that case, the action defined in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\VMApplet` is triggered. The default value is `SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe /pagefile`, which is what you see after login.

Remove the problem for which the page file couldn't be created or edit the registry key.